# jquery map function for checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm using the `map` function to get closest `li` based on checked status. I getting ordered list `id` but I need based on checked `id`.

```
var selectedItems = $("select").multiselect("getChecked").map(function () {
    var optGroup = findOptGroup($(this).closest('li'));
    var optGroupValue = optGroup.find('a').html();
    var value = this.id;
    return value;
}).get();
```

o/p :

```
"option-1", "option-2"
"option-0", "option-2"
```

need :

```
 "option-2", "option-0"
"option-2", "option-1"
```

I want output to be "option-2" and "option-1" based on checked

Comment: The output of `.map()` is in the same order as the inputs.

Comment: you should probably provide some html or a fiddle. Are you sure that you want your line to be `value = this.id` not `value = $(this).id` ?

Comment: @barmar i need to change the order

Comment: You can't do that with `.map()`. You need to reorder the array after it's returned by `.map()`. I don't understand the ordering criteria you want. What does _based on checked id_ mean?

Comment: You're setting the variable `optGroupValue`, but not using it for anything. What's the point of that?